# How to change/adapt loss function while using "class" incremental learning

Tags: machine-learning, learning

As a beginner on class incremental learning and trying to understand the general concept. In class incremental learning, we have a model that can make a classification between classes A, B, and C. By using data from another class D, we want to apply class incremental learning to obtain a model which can predict classes among A, B, C and D without training all data with all classes from scratch.

My **question** is, since our softmax (that we use to calculate loss (cross-entropy loss)) has a fixed size (3 in case of A, B, and C classes), how this can be possible? Do we change the loss in class incremental learning? How to deal with that?

Note 1: The video I watched to get an idea about class incremental learning is [iCaRL- incremental Classifier and Representation Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCKi41BHDAk&ab_channel=ManikVarma).

Note 2: I saw the catastrophic forgetting issue, but my question does not cover this. It is (I suppose) more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way is hierarchical learning. Train model #1 that learns A, B, or C. Then train model #2 that incrementally learns D and not D (i.e., A, B, or C). At prediction, model #2 makes the first prediction. If model #2 predicts not D, model #1 then predicts A, B, or C.